# ~/.mysql_history size limit

Tags: linux, mysql

My .mysql_history file size is limited to 300 lines.

I would like to keep the mysql history unlimited. However, I couldn't find any way to do it (in man page, and in google)

Can somebody please advise how to increase the size limitof .mysql_history from the default 300 to more (or unlimited)

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: Let us know if this works for you: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99099/6622

Comment: Can you explain your set-up? which server is connecting where and which history do you need when and why?

Comment: My setup is pretty standard: I am working on my local machine. From this local machine, I connect with `mysql-client` to a remote database. The history file is on my local machine in $HOME/.mysql_history

Comment: and both machines are wheezy? and can you connect via ssh to the other machine also? And why do you need so much history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysql` uses `readline` for the command line interface and for the history handling.

`readline` is configured in the `~/.inputrc` file and in `/etc/inputrc` system-wide.

You probably have a

```
set history-size 300
```

somewhere in there. Just remove that setting, or add a:

```
$if Mysql
set history-size -1
$endif
```

to your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not seem to have any effect. My `.mysql_history` has still precisely 300 lines

Comment: @MartinVegter, does `mysql` read your `~/.inputrc`? Confirm with `strace -fe open mysql ...`. What's in your `~/.inputrc` now (and before)? What does `env | grep MYSQL` return?

Comment: you are right. It works now. It did not work before, because `mysql` was an alias to `alias mysql='/usr/bin/rlwrap -a -pRED /usr/bin/mysql'`. When I disable the alias, it works. Any chance to use your trick with my alias active? (I tried using `$if rlwrap` in my .inputrc, but that does not seem to work)

Comment: @MartinVegter, use `rlwrap -s 99999999`, see the rlwrap man page. It's rlwrap that imposes that limit on 300, you can forget about the changes in `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : Please add this information in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a tail -F on the history file and pipe the output into a new file:

```
tail -F ~/.mysql_history >> ~/.mysql_complete_history
```

you will get all the commands, (although the file will grow quite a lot each time: the whole history file is added to the ~/.mysql_complete_history file time you quit the mysql console)

---

EDIT:

To correctly fill `~/.mysql_complete_history` with the exact output of `~/.mysql_history` use [this script by *Stephane Chazelas*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103161/how-can-i-monitor-a-file-that-fully-recreates-during-its-run)

Comment: That is very clever. Thanks. But unfortunately, this is not very practical.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it would work for you, but `man chattr` [reveals](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) there's a flag `a` which stands for "append only", so I'd give it a try and see. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clever suggestion. However this will not work for me, as I don't have `EXT4_FS_XATTR ` support in my kernel.

Comment: @MartinVegter, do you have any other FS_XATTR?

Comment: no, I don't have extended attributes support at all

Comment: @MartinVegter, is that some custom built kernel? Usual config includes `xattr` support even for `tmpfs`.

Comment: yes, this is a custom build kernel

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all queries that you used in all time you can enable the [general-log variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_general-log) (see also [How to enable MySQL Query Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479107/how-to-enable-mysql-query-log)).

Be aware that this will cause a lot of cpu and slow down mysql)

You could then create a new history file from that log each time before you enter the console by

```
cat /var/lib/mysql/yourhost.log | cut -f4-99|while read i; do echo $i\;; done | > ~/.mysql_history
```

this will put all commands that are executed on your server in your history file.

It is not perfect, cause commands that were over several lines are in a single history row now (but maybe you can fix that too, if you need it)

Comment: This would not work, unfortunately. I don't connect to the database from the mysql server, rather I connect from another machine. Therefore I don't have access to the log on the server.

Comment: If you have ssh access, you could cat the logfile on the other mashine through ssh into your local history file